# Fallout 3 GOTY edition doesn't start

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-3

I can start the launcher, but when I press play the game closes instead of running. Any one have an idea what the problem might be or away around it? Or any idea for something I can try would be appreciated.

By the way, I bought it through steam, no mods are installed (so it is "vanilla" GOTY edition), and I am using Windows 8.

My computer is a "Vision Computer" with an nVidia graphics card

I have tried both restarting the computer, and reinstalling the game. Both several times

Comment: May have something to do with MS closing down GfWLive last month. Can't check from here though.

Comment: MS? GfWLive? What are they

Comment: They would be "Microsoft" and "Games for Windows LIVE"

Comment: How would that have an effect

Comment: Fallout's achievements were through that unless purchased on steam. If it cannot talk to Microsoft's Games For Windows Live, then you cannot play the game. Do you have any logs for the game? (goto where it is installed and look for a "logs" folder)

Comment: @Shadur GFWL will be closed July 2014. And then this is still a rumor and has no evidence.

Comment: @ColeBusby That is wrong. For Fallout 3, logging into GFWL is optional.

Comment: Have you got any mods loaded?

Comment: What is your system build? Video card, OS and the like...

Comment: Do you have iut installed on the same drive as steam (C:) ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a summarized version of [this guide](http://steamcommunity.com//sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=149946772)

---

Please try these steps in the order listed.  After each step, test to see if it's working.

1. Update [Games for Windows Live](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient). 
   Sometimes this works, sometimes it doesn't.
2. Disable Games for Windows Live.

   Download [this disabler](http://fallout3.nexusmods.com/mods/1086/?tab=2&navtag=/ajax/modfiles/?id=1086&pUp=1)
3. Edit your INI file

   a. Open `My Documents\my games\Fallout3\FALLOUT.INI` in notepad

   b. Change `bUseThreadedAI=0` to `bUseThreadedAI=1`

   c. On the very next line type: `iNumHWThreads=2`

   d. Save and exit notepad
4. Download and install the [Unofficial Fallout 3 Patch](http://fallout3.nexusmods.com/mods/19122/?tab=2&navtag=/ajax/modfiles/?id=19122&pUp=1)

There are other options to fix less likely causes of your problem.  If this doesn't work let me know and I'll post some more obscure remedies.

Comment: Please don't just link to other places; summarize the information here.  That saves people a click, and ensures your answer is still valid, even if the page goes down.

Comment: Alright.  It's a pretty comprehensive startup guide, give me a few minutes to summarize it

Comment: Try to ensure that you grab the parts related to the problem at hand; a straight up copy and paste is just as bad as just a link.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Much better, but ensure you add the link to where you got it from.  Attribution is important.

Comment: Gotcha.  It was in the "reason for editing" but that didn't display. Editing now

Answer (score 0):

Go to the game settings from the launcher and adjust the graphics settings to medium or low levels. The game should start now.

Source: I had the exact same problem when I bought Fallout 3 GOTY a few months ago.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things. First off, even though it pains me to say it, try turning your computer off and on before anything.

If that does not work, right click on the game, and then hit DELETE LOCAL CONTENT. Then, re-install the game.

Also, what version of windows are you using?

Another thing you can try is:

> Basically, all you have to do is go to "\Documents\My Games\" and delete or rename the "Fallout3" folder so the game creates a new one. You should then be able to transfer old saves into the new folder. That's it.

[SOURCE](http://steamcommunity.com/app/22370/discussions/0/828938532572153405/)

Comment: Tried it, Doesn't work.

Comment: You tried everything? I'll go look up more solutions.